# Android intent for display url?

Tags: android, webview

for some time, I have been observing that modern android apps(Telegram) use a new way to open urls in the app. By default, the apps I have made, use ACTION_VIEW and the external browser open the url. These apps now manage that intent with a kind of in-app browser witch adapts to the same style. Any idea of what its?

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9o8G.png)

Answer (score 2):

Those are Custom chrome tabs.In app browser.instead of using webview to open your Url, you are going to customize your chrome browser,to look alike your app.you can modify the toolbar tab color as per your app theme .You could give enter and exit animation like fragments transition.So the user wouldn't feel a big transition from your app to browser.For implementation details check this link https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs

For security reasons also it could be useful,as because you are not going handle those url on you own or inside your app(there might be some security issues with JavaScript)

Answer (score 1):

This is done with WebView. You will find the documentation very interesting https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView

Comment: The answare to this behavior is android CustomTabs https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs

Answer (score 1):

This is achieved by `WebView` in an Activity that displays web pages. Instead of

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/");
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
 startActivity(intent);
```

You will load the page by calling:

```
webviewObj.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
```

You can check the [official document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView) which describes the whole process. Basic Usage of WebView has been described in [this blog](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/12/android-working-with-webview-building-a-simple-in-app-browser/) which is easy to comprehend and implement.

Answer (score 1):

**do the following:**

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

try this it helps you.